# Getting the public path on online server in laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, path

I Need to get the public path of my project laravel online , it's working with this line fine at local server but online it's not :

```
(public_path().'/website/'.$path);
```

So the problem is with that : `(public_path())` , how to make it working fine on online server too .

Comment: What's it doing wrong on your server?

Comment: Set `APP_URL` in the `.env` on your server

Comment: It's already set : 
APP_URL=http://premiumcaregold.com

The error is that , it can't find the path to create folder on it

Comment: where do you have that code? controller, view, somewhere else?

Comment: `public_path()` works fine no matter the environment or .env. Which part isn't working for you? What error do you get?

Comment: the code is at controller to upload files , it can't create the folder to the current path , that's the error that i have get

Comment: @DinaShaldoum probably you are having permission issues.

Comment: And if i have also facebook login error after update the website , even it was working fine before that that back to permission too ? 
the error is : 
`Client error: `GET https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/me?access_token=&fields=name,email,gender,verified,link&appsecret_proof=68eed75a049a91d21954e7c7a61d05c2d7e2a1a3aa29fd0f06c42aa6abddd127` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
{"error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","type":"OAuthExce (truncated...) `

Comment: @DinaShaldoum those two are different problems. About the facebook problem: have you added your URL in the Facebook App.

Comment: Yes , I do from last time and never change it

Answer (score 0):

**First you define below code in controller.php :**

```
   class myproject extends Controller
   {

     function __construct()
    {
            define('HTTP_ROOT', asset('/') . 'public/');
    }
  }

 new myproject();
```

*and then you use HTTP_ROOT in place of public_path().*

Comment: `asset()` returns URL rather than physical path.

Comment: ok but you see that i have concatenation with public which related it with physical path

Comment: `asset()` returns something like *https://your-website.com/*, OP is asking where to **store** files. `public_path()` returns something like */var/www/your-website.com/public/*. What you have typed in your answer is equivalent to `asset('public')`.